# After renaming uploaded image, broken image is shown when fetched from database

Tags: php, mysql, image, mysqli, file-upload

If I upload a same named image, my code works fine to rename it in my location but when it's fetched from database, the duplicate image is broken. My code for renaming and storing the image is:

**insert_image.php**

```
$image      = $_FILES['image'];
$name       = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$temp_name  = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$newname = $name; 
//print_r($_FILES); 
$location = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/images/'.basename($name); 
$image_path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/images/';   
$extention = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(file_exists($location)){
     $increment = 0;
     list($name, $extention) = explode('.', $location);
     while(file_exists($location)) {
         $increment++;
         $location = $name. $increment . '.' . $extention;
         //print_r($location);
         $newname = $name. $increment . '.' . $extention;
     }
 } 

 mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT INTO post(username, post, image) VALUES('$uname', '$post', '$newname')");

if(isset($newname)){
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $location) && is_writable($location)){
        //echo 'File uploaded successfully';
    }
    else{
        //echo "Failed to move...";
    }
}
```

any kind of better suggestions will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `location` variable (inside while loop) your are storing only file name. You also want full path. change your code as below

```
$image      = $_FILES['image'];
$name       = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$temp_name  = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$newname = $name; 
//print_r($_FILES); 
$location = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/images/'.basename($name); 
$image_path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/images/';   
$extention = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(file_exists($location)){
     $increment = 0;
     list($name, $extention) = explode('.', $name);
     while(file_exists($location)) {
         $increment++;
         $location = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/images/'.$name. $increment . '.' . $extention;
         $newname = $name. $increment . '.' . $extention;
     }
 } 

 mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT INTO post(username, post, image) VALUES('$uname', '$post', '$newname')");

if(isset($newname)){
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $location) && is_writable($location)){
        //echo 'File uploaded successfully';
    }
    else{
        //echo "Failed to move...";
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't work. checked it. It changes the value of $location to something like this :  C:\xampp\htdocs\proj/images/C:\xampp\htdocs\proj/images/imagen.jpg

Comment: can you please recheck and suggest something?

Comment: will you check updated answer? I have change this line : `list($name, $extention) = explode('.', $name);`